# What's the correct format to set a default value to a DateTime aura:attribute?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datetime, aura, aura-attribute

I would like to set a default value to a DateTime `aura:attribute`,
 but could not find the correct format. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
<aura:attribute name="myDateTime" type="DateTime" default="1981-08-26T00:00:00.000Z"/>
```

When I try to save, I receive the following error: *Failed to save undefined: For input string: "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z".*

It seems I can use a number that will end up being added to the Unix Epoch time but well, that's not really convenient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very interesting question.

I did some research on it and found this [gitHub repository](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/test/components/attributesTest/defaultValue/defaultValue.cmp), someone has tried to play with default values of all kinds of basic types.

**Scene 1:**

Simply putting the below line doesn't work.

```
<aura:attribute type="Datetime" name="datetimeDefaultWithTimeString" default="2013-03-06T10:17:36.789Z"/>
```

however if you do the exact same line with `type="Date"`, it takes the whole thing and displays as Datetime.

```
<aura:attribute type="Date" name="dateDefaultWithTimeString" default="2013-03-06T10:17:36.789Z"/>
```

**Scene 2:**

In the other hand, datetime attributes take string as default value and the string needs to be a digit.

```
<aura:attribute type="DateTime" name="dateTimeDefaultZero" default="0"/>
```

This would default the attribute to `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`, start of calendar I guess.

Again, defaulting it to 1 will increase the mili second part by 1, i.e `1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z`

```
<aura:attribute type="DateTime" name="dateTimeDefaultWithString" default="1"/>
```

Similarly, defaulting it to 1000 would increase the time by 1 second. So in short, it takes millisecond value and adds to `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.

**Scene 3:**

Now again, the following is allowing me to provide a full length datetime string as default value and its displaying the same too.

```
<aura:attribute type="DateTime" name="datetimeDefaultWithTimeLiteralExp" default="{!'2016-03-06T10:17:36.789Z'}"/>
```

I could have just put the 3rd scene directly as an answer but I would like to see what other experts think about this case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer ! I guess we would all expect to have "2016-03-06T10:17:36.789Z" to work directly, but at least it working with this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Many Peoples searching for this, but this is the right place to comment.

**Working Default format in Lightning design system:** `2018-01-06T00:00`

**Javascript:**

```
moment(new Date(), "DD-MM-YYYY").add(1,'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD")+'TT00:00')
```